# Confusion over initialisation, instantiation and interface

Tags: java, interface, initialization

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn the concept of initialisation. I saw this statement online:

```
List<Integer> numList  = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

I understand interface type can't be instantiated. But `Arrays.asList()` method returns a object that implement `List<>` interface. Does this statement count as initialisation? Have I created an instance of class that implement `List<>` interface?

Comment: @user2004685 What's the purpose of the extra `ArrayList<>` when `Arrays.asList()` returns an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: Class `Arrays` have an inner class named `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`. It implements interface `List<T>`. `Arrays.asList()` returns its instance.

Comment: Instantiation and initialization mean different things. Instantiation is when you create an object with `new`. Initialization is when fields of an object are assigned during construction, sometimes also used for initial assignment of local variables etc. Basically (what fits in a comment), *instantiation = creating an object* and *initialization = assigning a variable the first time*. The terms get used in some other contexts as well but they are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the statement counts as initialization; you initialized the `numList` variable by assigning it a value: the value returned by `Arrays.asList()`.

When `Arrays.asList(arr)` is called, it instantiates an `ArrayList` based on the input array `arr`. An `ArrayList` is a specific implementation of the abstract class `AbstractList`, which itself implements the `List`. So, while `ArrayList` does not directly implement the `List` interface, it can be treated like one through *[polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)*.

For more details, refer to The [Java Tutorial on Creating Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) and [Java Tutorials on Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html), especially the section on [using an interface as a type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceAsType.html). You may also benefit by reading the tutorials about [Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) and [Initializing Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

Answer (score 1):

A reference variable can be declared as a **class type** or an **interface type**.

If the variable is declared as an interface type, it can reference any object of any class that implements the interface.

So you have created an object which is being referenced by the interface variable.

Answer (score 0):

- Does this statement count as initialization?

  Yest it does. Because you initialize the reference variable `numList`.
- Have I created an instance of class that implement List<> interface?

  No, You didn't created an instance of class that implement List<> interface.But The `Arrays.asList()` method created an instance of class `ArrayList`returned the reference of that object to you.

If you read the source code you will find something like:

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<>(a);
}
```

Now `new ArrayList<>(a);` this statement creating an instance.
And yes  `ArrayList` implement `List` interface.

Comment: please don't get me wrong, i am ok with down vote,but  can some one correct me please before I delete this answer.